# Dynamically load dataframe using a for-loop in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop, pyspark

I am trying to dynamically load some data into dataframe in pyspark. I want to pass in a bunch of table names and iteratively load them and name the dataframes as in the list.

Here's what I have tried:

```py
rel_path = 'some/path/'

tables = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for table in candidate_tables:
  table_path = rel_path + table + '/*'
  table = spark.read.parquet(table_path)

>>> table
```

I found that I was only able to read the first table (a) and the table name is 'table'. Is it even possible to do it this way or just stick back to loading one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to create dynamic number of tables in the global environment. The easiest solution is to use a dictionary to hold all your tables:

```
rel_path = 'some/path/'

names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
tables = {}

for name in names:
  table_path = rel_path + name + '/*'
  tables[name] = spark.read.parquet(table_path)
```

Then you can access your table via `table['a'], table['b']` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to see how to improve repetition of loading the tables which could be a lot.